# Parsing json with ion on android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse this json

```
["user": { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" },"user": { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" },"user": { "ver": "2.0-2.1", "name": "Eclair", "api": "API level 5-7" }]
```

with this code

```
private void load() {
    if (loading != null && !loading.isDone() && !loading.isCancelled()) {
        return;
    }
    String url="http://www.ribony.com/json.php";
    loading=Ion.with(this,url)
            .asJsonArray()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                public void onCompleted(Exception e,JsonArray result) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("HATA","YUKLEME HATASI");
                        Log.w("DETAY",e);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
                        Log.w("ADAPTOR","OK");
                        tweetAdapter.add(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

When I try to run this app,app is crashing.Here is my logcat : http://prntscr.com/44jhdf

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: It is invalid JSON. `Parse error on line 2:
[    "user": {        "ver": "
-----------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'`

Comment: @Aniruddha Can you give an example like this json ? I can't see where is the error.

Comment: Make use of jsonlint.com. You will get to know where the error is.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your json, the correct json looks like:

```
    [
  {
    "user": {
      "ver": "1.5",
      "name": "Cupcake",
      "api": "API level 3"
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "ver": "1.6",
      "name": "Donut",
      "api": "API level 4"
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "ver": "2.0-2.1",
      "name": "Eclair",
      "api": "API level 5-7"
    }
  }
]
```

To verifiy if your json is correct, you can use http://jsoneditoronline.org/index.html